# Is the tab on this voltage regulator D2Pak package connected to ground?

Tags: voltage-regulator

I have looked through the [datasheet.](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/20005685A-1082375.pdf) The specific piece I am using is a MIC29300-12 with a D2Pak (TO263) package. I cannot find anywhere where it clearly states what the tab is connected to. Assistance is appreciated.

Comment: The downvotes are because the question does not show much research, as the answer is literally written in the datasheet at multiple places.

Answer (score 3):

You say you have looked through the datasheet but you must have literally looked, not read. You always need to *read* the datasheet thoroughly. Looking at page 23, you come across this table:

[image]

I have highlighted the bit you should have read. In fact, it is even repeated in the table just under it:

[image]

This information was not hiding, it was pretty easy to find. Reading the information properly in the datasheet will 9 times out of 10 give the answer you are looking for.

Comment: I should have included more detail. I did see that but the package I am using is the D2PAK, and was unsure if this fell under that umbrella. Table 3-1 is for the three pin packages, the TO263-3 being the one I am using.

Comment: The 2 table sI have included cover the 3 and 5 pin packages. Both confirm that yes, the tab is connected to GND

Answer (score 1):

In table

> TABLE 3-2: PIN FUNCTION TABLE

Is noted that:

> TAB is also connected internally to the IC’s ground
>   on D-PAK

Comment: I should have included more detail. I did see that but the package I am using is the D2PAK, and was unsure if this fell under that umbrella. Table 3-1 is for the three pin packages, the TO263-3 being the one I am using. Table 3-2 shows the five pin packages.