# D2PAK 2-pin NMOS?

Tags: mosfet, surface-mount, nmos

I was looking up high-voltage NMOSs on DigiKey and found [this entry for model STB12NM60N](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/stmicroelectronics/STB12NM60N/1852399). However, it appears to be a two-pin NMOS (at least, I'm not sure how that tab connects to anything). Based on the pin numbering, as far as I can understand it looks like the NMOS has a gate and source terminal but no drain. I couldn't find anything after looking through the datasheet, and [the only other article](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/400485/is-the-tab-on-this-voltage-regulator-d2pak-package-connected-to-ground) I've found on D2PAK SMD components just had the tab route internally to another external pin - a different situation to the STB12NM60N which just doesn't have a drain terminal.

My question is two-fold: (a) Does the STB12NM60N have a drain terminal (i.e., all three drain, gate, and source terminals), and (b) how can I route traces to the drain terminal? Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tab is the drain terminal.

Route the tab as best in your application.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Is it even possible to route the tab? From the D2PAK footprint in the datasheet, it appears like the tab is left hanging above the board. Am I supposed to solder an external wire to the tab? It feels illogical for an SMD component, but maybe that's just how this package works.

Comment: @asyndeton256 When we say tab, we aren't referring to the cut pin. We call them tabs because the term comes from through-hole packages like TO-220 where they actually are very prominent tabs. On a SMD component like a D2Pak it is less a giant tab and more a giant pad with a tiny tab sticking out the edge of the package.

Comment: Ah, so the giant pad in the footprint was routed to the tiny tab sticking out - thanks for the help! It's my first time seeing an SMD component like this, although now that you've explained it it makes a lot more sense in hindsight. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @asyndeton256 Hmm yeah I guess in the CG model it doesn't show the pad and tab as one piece. In reality when you look on the bottom though it's just one piece of metal.

Answer (score 5):

The tab/pad is a pin. Same as pin 2 (the cut pin) Not your fault. Datasheet unclear. Can't know without experience. The tab is not always electrically connected though, especially if there is a functional pin elsewhere so all functionality is covered without the tab. Then it could go either way. Electrically isolated tabs are more likely in through-hole and less likely in SMD. But in this case you need three pins and pin 2 is cut so the tab must serve the function of pin 2.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it helps to know that D2PAK is a mechanically modified TO-220, where the middle pin and the screw hole tab are internally connected. When using a TO-220, you would use an isolating, heat conducting shim between the tab and a heat sink, and fasten it with a plastic screw or a clip.

However, for SMD, the copper in the PCB is in fact the heat sink, so all of that stuff became obsolete. So the screw hole was removed by shortening the tab, and the middle pin could be cut short, leaving a 3 pad SMD device.

I2PAK (TO-262) is an interim step which can only be fastened to heat sink with a clip rather than screw.

So TO220 became TO-262 by filing down the screw hole part of the heat sink tab, TO-262 became TO-263 (D2PAK) by bending the pins, for SMD use. In this case, the middle pin became then obsolete (but there are other D2PAK devices where this isn't the case).

So yes, it has a drain terminal, it's the rather large third SMD terminal.
And knowing this, routing to it should be fairly obvious, with one caveat. The drain terminal should be well connected to plenty of copper in the PCB, for cooling.
Easy to do it it's connected by vias to an inner supply layer (think half bridge driver), easy to forget if not.